# Background Image Fader - Delay before first image

Tags: jquery

I found a piece of jQuery code which I have manipulated to work in a project I am working on.

My main issue is the higher I set the delay the longer it takes for the first slide to come in e.g. the delay is set to "5000" so it takes 5 seconds to load the first slide and I just get a white background, is there something that needs to be tweaked to show the first slide on load.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kellyhawker/f7ky55fr/)

```
function cycleBackgrounds() {
var index = 0;

$imageEls = $('.imageCon .slide'); // Get the images to be cycled.

setInterval(function () {
    // Get the next index.  If at end, restart to the beginning.
    index = index + 1 < $imageEls.length ? index + 1 : 0;

    // Show the next
    $imageEls.eq(index).addClass('showImg');

    // Hide the previous
    $imageEls.eq(index - 1).removeClass('showImg');
}, 5000);
};

// Document Ready.
$(function () {
cycleBackgrounds();
});
```

Comment: Does just giving the starting image a class of `showImg` not work?

Comment: Here I was looking at the code and not the obvious, sometimes you need a second set of eyes, thanks that worked.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Sometimes I need a third set. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was made aware that I didn't have the class on the active div for the first image.